# Java Formatter giving a NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing

In Java Swing, I am creating a text area for logs given through the program. I created the panel and handler. In my overridden method `publish(LogRecord record)`, I receive a NullPointerException when I attempt to format the LogRecord, however, I previously checked if the LogRecord was loggable (not null). Here is my code:

*WindowHandler*

```
package swing;

import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class WindowHandler extends Handler {

    private LogWindowPanel window = null;
    private static WindowHandler handler = null;

    private WindowHandler() {
        LogManager manager = LogManager.getLogManager();
        String className = this.getClass().getName();
        String level = manager.getProperty(className + ".level");
        setLevel(level != null ? Level.parse(level) : Level.INFO);
        if (window == null)
            window = new LogWindowPanel();
    }

    public static synchronized WindowHandler getInstance() {
        if (handler == null)
            handler = new WindowHandler();
        return handler;
    }

    public synchronized JPanel getWindowPanel() {
        if (window == null)
            window = new LogWindowPanel();
        return window;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void publish(LogRecord record) {
        String message = null;
        if (!isLoggable(record))
            return;
        message = getFormatter().format(record);
        window.showInfo(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws SecurityException {
    }

}
```

Error traces at `message = getFormatter().format(record);` specifically at `.format(record);`

*Call in MainWindowFrame*

```
handler = WindowHandler.getInstance();
logger = Logger.getLogger("logging.handler");
logger.addHandler(handler);
logger.info("Hello World");
add(handler.getWindowPanel());
```

*Stack trace*

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at WindowHandler.publish(WindowHandler.java:41)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:765)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:788)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.info(Logger.java:1489)
    at MainWindowFrame.<init>(MainWindowFrame.java:76)
    at main$1.run(main.java:15)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: NPEs are about the easiest problem you'll ever get to debug! What does `getFormatter()` return? What is the value of `record`?

Comment: From the [Handler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html#getFormatter--) re `getFormatter()`: `the Formatter (may be null)`. So no guarantee that it's not null.

Comment: @GregKopff just checked. it is null indeed :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I checked, it is actually null. How am I able to get an instance of formatter? solution?

Comment: As the other commenters noted (though one quite rudely), `getFormatter()' is returning null. You'll want to either check the result of getFormatter() for null and use a default/fallback formatter, or skip the formatting when getFormatter() returns null.

Comment: Again, as per the API: `Handler classes typically use LogManager properties to set default values for the Handler's Filter, Formatter, and Level. See the specific documentation for each concrete Handler class.` Have you looked into this? And what concrete Handler are you using? Note that I am not familiar with this class and have never used it myself, and so about all I can do (and you should be doing) is to try to scour the API for gleanings of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How am I able to get an instance of formatter?

To get a none null formatter you can use

```
setFormatter( new SimpleFormatter());
```

or create your own custom formatter, for example:

```
public class CustomFormatter extends Formatter{

.....

}
```

and use it :  setFormatter( new CustomFormatter());
I hope it clarifies